# Wrap content around Element on right, then Responsively above when exceeding min-width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, responsive-design

I am trying to wrap text around an image that is positioned on the right and have the image shifted below the text when the screen becomes too small.

With these additional requirements:

- The Text component has a minimum width for it's content next to the column (say 300px), which when exceeded pushes the image below the text.
- The image component's size is unknown.
- Images will be rendered at their native size, which may determine whether it is rendered to the right of the text or below it.
- The same rules must apply when printing

**Example**

[image: spec]

---

**What have I tried?**

- https://codepen.io/CrocoDillon/pen/kmGCw (flawed as the image size is not pre-determined)

My current solution is a combination of various approaches. It's dirty/hacky as it uses JS to achieve part of it's goals which end up failing the print requirement.

It works as follows:

- In html, render the IMAGE after the TEXT and floating the IMAGE to the right so that image is on right with text wrapped around it.
- In JS, on window resize, `if windowWidth - imageWidth > 300px` (our min content width), update the style of the container to use flex-direction column-reverse so that the image appears below the text.

It fails the Print Requirement as the min-width check happens on window resize based on widths within window. Ideally it should now be based on the widths within the paper size/layout.

It is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="article-template-1">
    <div class="article-content" ng-style="articleContentResponsiveStyle">
        <div class="main-image-holder">
            <div ng-repeat="imageLink in images">
                <img ng-attr-src="{{imageLink.Location}}"
                     ng-attr-title="{{imageLink.Description}}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <span model="Article.Content" bind-html-compile>{{Article.Content}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#newsArticle .article-content-holder .article-template-1 .article-content .main-image-holder {
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#newsArticle .article-content-holder .article-template-1 .article-content .main-image-holder img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
var appWindow = angular.element(this.$window);
appWindow.bind("resize", this.updateArticleResponsiveStyle);

private exceedsMinContent:boolean = null;
private updateArticleResponsiveStyle = () => {
    // The minimum size that inline content needs to be before images are repositioned
    const minArticleWidth = 300;

    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let maxImageContainerWidth = windowWidth - minArticleWidth;
    let imageContainerWidth = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('main-image-holder'))[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

    const previouslyExceedsMinContent = this.exceedsMinContent;
    this.exceedsMinContent = imageContainerWidth > maxImageContainerWidth;

    if (previouslyExceedsMinContent !== this.exceedsMinContent) {

        this.$scope.articleContentResponsiveStyle =
            this.exceedsMinContent ?
            {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "column-reverse"
            } :
            {
                "display": "block"
            }

        this.$scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

---

Yes, I find this incomplete solution hacky and would prefer a pure CSS approach if possible.